# Datatype have changed from Text10 -> Code10, what is the equivalent type in mysql?

Tags: mysql, types, ssis, etl, sqldatatypes

I have a ssis package that reads data from a third party database, and then writes that data to my database.
I have received an email from them that the following from their database is changing:

- Table 6014407 Audit Roll:

  - Field 11 - "Unit":
  - Name change: "Unit" -> "Unit of Measure Code"

    - Data type change: Text10 -> Code10

my current definition in sql when creating the table for Unit is  NVARCHAR(10) for Text10, but I'd like to know what the equivalent datatype is for Code10, as I'm not familiar with that type

Comment: what is the database provider? third - party doesn't mean something specific

Comment: Unfortunately I am unaware about the database provider, what I meant with third party is that its my customer's buisness partner.

Comment: Try using the NUMERIC(10) data type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are working with Microsoft Dynamics NAV since it supports `TEXT` and `CODE` data types.

Referring to [Text Data Type in Dynamics NAV documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/text-data-type):

> This simple data type denotes a text string.
>   
> ...
>   The Text data type supports Unicode.

In addition, from [Code Data Type in Dynamics NAV documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/code-data-type):

> It denotes a special type of string that is converted to uppercase and removes any trailing or leading spaces.
>   
> ...
>   The Code data type supports Unicode.

**Based on that you can still use `NVARCHAR(10)` for this data type.**

Comment: And, if using MySQL, specify utf8mb4.